# Jenkins Windows Slave Not displaying Stdout In Console Log

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, build-server

I have a Windows Master running Jenkins and another PC configured as a Windows Slave. I have started the windows slave from both a web browser and from the command line with the same results. The stdout from the build running on my slave isn't captured in the console log on master. Is this possibly due to the fact that I am manually launching the slave so the master doesn't have a connection to the stdout? Are there ways to resolve this? I am considering installing cywin on the slave and seeing if using ssh resolves the issue, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in "manually" launching a slave. I'd start by completely disabling the Firewall first, just to see if something there is blocking communication

Comment: This is a GUI application writing to the console. How I was attaching to the console was the issue and I was able to resolve it. I need to go back and compare it to my previous code to determine what was actually the issue, as another developer wrote the previous code, but for now it is resolved.